# I am not making the jump from IF-Then-Else to IIF in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am struggling with Report Builder and would appreciate so help.
I want to find a percentage of ChargeOffAmount / LoanAmount based on a date.

IF(Fields!Chargeoffdate.Value is less than 2 years ago then Sum(Fields!ChargeOffAmount.Value) 
IF(Fields!Chargeoffdate.Value is more than 2 years ago or there is no date, then ignore the (Fields!ChargeOffAmount.Value)

**Divided by**

IF(Fields!Chargeoffdate.Value is less than 2 years ago then Sum(Fields!LoanAmount.Value) 
IF(Fields!Chargeoffdate.Value is more than 2 years ago or there is no date, then ignore the (Fields!LoanAmount.Value)

**Equals the charge-off ratio**

I am too embarrassed to show my failed efforts.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the structure of your data nor the report, I guess that each *ChargeOffAmount* and each *LoanAmount* has a *Chargeoffdate* and you want to take into account only the values of the last 2 years.

Of Course, you could use a filter (or `WHERE` clause in your Dataset) to restrict the records to only the last 2 years, but I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Chargeoffdate.Value >= Today.AddYears(-2), Fields!ChargeOffAmount.Value, 0))/Sum(IIf(Fields!Chargeoffdate.Value >= Today.AddYears(-2), Fields!LoanAmount.Value, 0))
```

Comment: Wow! This is amazing.  You read my mind.  Your solution did reveal a problem.  This is probably why you asked about the dataset.  I do not wish to filter at the dataset level.  Here is what the data set looks like:

Comment: Wow! This is amazing.  You read my mind.  Your solution did reveal a problem.  This is probably why you asked about the dataset.  I do not wish to filter at the dataset level.  Here is what the data set looks like

Account Loan Amount  Last Payment Chargeoffdate  ChargeOffAmount Status
1242  $20000 6/25/18 -   -   Open
1252  $19000 6/25/18 -   -   Open
1262  $00  3/25/16 5/25/17  $11000  C/O 
1272  $0  1/25/15 3/25/15  $29000  C/O
1282  $50000 6/25/18 -   -   Open
1292  $0  4/25/18 -   -   Paid

Comment: Accounts with a Loan Amount do not have a Chargeoffdate.Value or ChargeOffAmount.Value.   I need all of the Sum(Fields!LoanAmount.Value)
in the denominator so the comparision to ChargeOffAmount.Value.   

In the dataset above the Loan Amount is $89000.  The charge-off amount in the last 2-Year is $11000.  Therefore, what I am looking for is an equation that finds $11000 / $89000 = 12.35%

Comment: Ok, so how do you know that the Chargeoffdate of the values that make up $89000 are within the last 2 years? I think that you have to look at the LastPayment date instead. If you agree, just change that field in the two conditions of my formula: `=Sum(IIf(Fields!LastPayment.Value >= Today.AddYears(-2), Fields!ChargeOffAmount.Value, 0))/Sum(IIf(Fields!LastPayment.Value >= Today.AddYears(-2), Fields!LoanAmount.Value, 0))`